# Add CATextLayer with addSublayer()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, layer

I write this code :

```
let myAttributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-HeavyOblique", size: 15.0)! ,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
]
let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: textRightUpLabel!, attributes: myAttributes )
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = myAttributedString
textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - width + textMarginRightUpLabel, y: 8, width: width, height: height)
self.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
```

and this work well but it's seems to add 2 layers how show this in my storyboard :

[image: storyboard image]

So the question is: Why the text "3 DAYS LEFT" are show 2 times? One in the good place and another one behind the ShapeLayer?

Thanks to your reply

Comment: Where is the rest of your code. Is this a designable?

Comment: @agibson007 Yes this is in a designable class

Comment: so where do you call this method.  How may times?  We need the rest of the code to determine why there are multiple instance.

Comment: @agibson007 Yes, each times I update the storyboard the function was called : https://pastebin.com/mgma51SG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the texlayer variable out of that function and make it a variable of the view.

```
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
```

Where you add it to the layer check and see if the layer already contains the textLayer like this instead of adding it over and over. Sorry this is a bit messy on mobile. Will check it and clean it up when I am back at my Mac.

```
if let subLs = self.sublayers, subLs.contains(textLayer) == true{//do nothing
 }else{
      self.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you !